# Custom plotting function error R - Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Species' not found

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I'm trying to write a function that outputs plots to be used over multiple standardized dataframes.
I've been trying to wrap my head around what I'm doing wrong and I can't figure it out.

```
# function to plot 
plotify <- function(data, x, y){
      
  ggplot2::ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + 
            geom_bar(stat = "identity")
} 

plotify(iris, Species, Sepal.Length)

## Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Species' not found
```

How does the above code throw me an error but if were to run the following code,

`ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +  geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

I get the plots I need? How have I screwed up in writing the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is about [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html). Here, you can use [curly-curly](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) to make it work

```
plotify <- function(data, x, y){
  
  ggplot2::ggplot(data, ggplot2::aes({{ x }}, {{ y }})) + 
    ggplot2::geom_bar(stat = "identity")
} 

plotify(iris, Species, Sepal.Length)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Will definitely have to read about non standard evaluation!